# Comparing a sample correlation to a fixed value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

is there a test that compares the observed correlation to a certain value ? for instance : is my correlation equal to 0.8 (0.8 not being any population's correlation, it's just a value that is fixed)
i'd like to know the statistic of the test (if there is any)

Comment: Does [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/distribution-of-sample-correlation) answer your question?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Can you be more specific, how it doesn't? The answer there gives the (asymptotic) distribution of the a function of sample correlation coefficient for some assumed value of population correlation. This can be used to get the critical value for your hypothesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distribution of sample correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7218/distribution-of-sample-correlation)

Comment: Yes, there's a standard test: compare the Fisher Z-transform of the correlation to the Z-transform of the value.  See https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/09/20/fishers-transformation-correlation.html for one online resource.  A fuller account can be found in standard textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a path to an answer, where I first cite efforts in a regression setting discussed over six pages, for example, in this educational source: [Non-Zero Null Tests for Simple Linear Regression](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Non-Zero_Null_Tests_for_Simple_Linear_Regression.pdf).

So, how does this analysis of a regression case constitute an answer for a correlation test in general? Consider a special case of transformed values for Y and a single variable X, where the data was centered around the respective sample means and scale by their respective standard deviations.

Now, I claim we have an instance where the standardized regression coefficient are so-called beta coefficients. The latter, for the case of one explanatory variable, equates to the Pearson correlation coefficient. [Supporting reference](http://dmcglinn.github.io/quant_methods/lessons/standardized_beta_coefficients.html), for example, to quote:

> Standardized β coefficients: This mini-lesson is to introduce the concept of standardized regression coefficients in R. A standardized regression coefficient is simply the β estimate from a regression on standardized variables. A standardized variable is a variable that has a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. One reason for standardizing variables is that you can interpret the β estimates as partial correlation coefficients.

where with one variable X, it is the Pearson correlation coefficient.